# using php and mysql to populate html select isnt sorting

Tags: php, mysql, html

I'm wanting to fetch all the values of the "Category" column of a table called "Category', then sort them alpha while ignoring case. What I have doesn't sort them at all. Please help, I can't quite figure how how to apply other examples to this situation. I apologize if I didn't get the formatting right for stackoverflow.

```
//--The purpose of this is to populate a HTML select with the proper options
    $MysqlUser = "brad";
    $MysqlPass = "mysql";
    $MysqlDatabase = "whispers";
    $connection = mysql_connect("localhost","$MysqlUser","$MysqlPass");
    if (!$connection){
        die(mysql_errno() . mysql_error());
        }

        mysql_select_db("$MysqlDatabase", $connection);
        $result = mysql_query( "SELECT Category FROM Category "); 

        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        asort($row);
        foreach ( $row as $field ) {
            print "<option value=\"$field\"> $field </option>";
        }
        }
    mysql_close($connection);
    //--End HTML select
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an ORDER BY in your select clause. Rows in a database table have no order, that's way you have to specify an order when you select.

```
SELECT Category FROM Category ORDER BY Category
```

Comment: it works as promised. Thank you so much! Time to buy a FM so I can RTFM.